# How to change the order of algorithm number and name in algorithm2e?

Tags: babel, algorithm2e

I have to write an algorithm in Hungarian, where the caption must look like:

> **1.3. Algoritmus:** caption of alg

instead of the usual style

> **Algorithm 1.3:** caption of alg.

Until now I had no problem as the package `babel` was doing all the work, but changing from `algorithm`-`algorithmic` to the `algorithm2e` package, it fails.

Anyone know the way to do so?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine an internal macro of `algorithm2e`, namely `\fnum@algocf`. Put

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@algocf}{\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt\thealgocf\nobreakspace\algorithmcfname}}
\makeatother
```

into your preamble.
Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@algocf}{\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt\thealgocf\nobreakspace\algorithmcfname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
      }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
      }
    }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does the job. To be perfect I corrected it by adding the dot after the numbering:
`\renewcommand{\fnum@algocf}{\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt\thealgocf.\nobreakspace\algorithmcfname}}`